# pgsql DELETE + LIMIT + JOIN + ORDER

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL and I have a game where there are tournaments for the players to participate in.

I have the following tables to describe players and tournament players (the ones that are participating in a given tournament). These tables are simplified to contain only what are used in the query:

```sql
CREATE TABLE player (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    username VARCHAR(255),
    push_notification_token VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE tournament_player (
    tournament_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    player_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    victories INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

When a tournament ends I want to delete all tournament players in chunks of 100, I would also like to have then ordered by their placing in the tournament (victories DESC).

I am currently using the following query to delete, limit and join:

```sql
DELETE FROM tournament_player tp 
    USING player p
    WHERE tp.player_id = p.id 
        AND (tp.tournament_id, tp.player_id) IN (
            SELECT tournament_id, player_id 
            FROM tournament_player
        LIMIT 100)
RETURNING tp.player_id, tp.victories, 
    p.username, p.push_notification_token;
```

There are two questions I have:

- How do I also order it (DESC) by tournament_player (victories)
- Is this query wasting resources or is it optimized enough? (I don't mean adding INDEX to a field)

Answer (score 1):

You can just add `order by tp.victories desc` in your inner query before `limit` to have the result in your desire order.

```
DELETE FROM tournament_player tp 
    USING player p
    WHERE tp.player_id = p.id 
        AND (tp.tournament_id, tp.player_id) IN (
            SELECT tournament_id, player_id 
            FROM tournament_player
            order by tp.victories desc
        LIMIT 100)
RETURNING tp.player_id, tp.victories, 
    p.username, p.push_notification_token;
```

Instead of `IN` you can also use `exits` as below:

```
DELETE FROM tournament_player tp 
    USING player p
    WHERE tp.player_id = p.id 
        AND exists
        (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM tournament_player tpr
            where tpr.tournament_id=tp.tournament_id and tpr.player_id=tp.player_id
            order by tp.victories desc
            LIMIT 100
        )
    RETURNING tp.player_id, tp.victories, 
    p.username, p.push_notification_token;
```

Is below part really necessary?

```
 USING player p
    WHERE tp.player_id = p.id
```

If you can remove this joining your query will be faster. I assume that all the players in `tournament_player` are in `player` table. So, this join is not necessary.

Comment: I put this join part because `username` and `push_notification_token` I retrieve from the `player` table and not the `player_tournament` table. Would it still work if it was removed?

Comment: If you need those information then that join is necessary. Sorry I missed that part.

Comment: can you provide some sample data in text format so that I can recreate the scenario.